# HTTP 400 error while sending POST request

Tags: python, http, urllib, http-status-code-400

I am trying to POST to an endpoint using python 3.6. But I keep getting the HTTP 400 error. Here is the exact error I am getting:

```
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request
```

Below is the relevant snippet of what I am doing. Think I am doing something basic wrong.

```
message = 'symbol=ETHBTC&side=SELL&type=LIMIT&timeInForce=GTC&quantity=0.0024420613350075726&price=0.049455&timestamp=1513838413392&recvWindow=20000'

signature = hmac.new(secretKey.encode('utf-8'),message.encode('utf-8'),hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()

parameters = {'symbol': 'ETHBTC', 'side': 'SELL', 'type': 'LIMIT', 'timeInForce': 'GTC', 'quantity': 0.0024420613350075726, 'price': 0.049455, 'timestamp': 1513838413392, 'recvWindow': 20000, 'signature': signature}


data = parse.urlencode(parameters).encode('ascii');
url = 'https://api.binance.com/api/v3/order/test'

request = urllib.request.Request(url, data);
request.add_header('X-MBX-APIKEY', apiKey);
response = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
```

Link to the full API: https://www.binance.com/restapipub.html#user-content-account-endpoints. Also updated the actual parameters i am using.

Comment: It seems your endpoint is an api. Maybe your parameters are not declared in a compatible way with the api.

Comment: I'm not sure you need to call `urlencode()` yourself, I'd expect `urllib` to do that automatically.

Comment: add link to API documentation, and which function in API you try to use.

Comment: Added the API and the actual parameter values i am using. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Figured out what the problem was. It has to do with min order size.